# Quantity precision for Quote product

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am facing issue related to precision for quantity of quote product.Its taking 5 precision values while i have setup 2 precision in quantity field and i also setup "Whole and fraction" in price list item.Decimal supported value in product also have 2.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by calling below function on onload of QuoteProduct form:-

`function OnLoad() 
{
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("quantity").setPrecision(2);
}`